# Set first visible item in gridview

Tags: java, android, gridview

I need to have gridview scrolling to the first item onResume of my activity. It has only the vertical scrolling.

I have tried the following, but it didn't work...

```
gridView.setSelection(0);
gridView.scrollY(0);
```

Can someone help please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I have solved my problem!**. I have implemented onActivityResult and called the activity for adding a new item, with a known request code. Then upon return, and the result was OK; I use gridView.smoothScrollTo(0), which worked like charm! See code below...

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, AddNewActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_ADD_NEW);


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_ADD_NEW_CLOTHING_ITEM)
        {
            gridView.smoothScrollToPosition(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try gridView.scrollTo(0,0) or gridVIew.smoothScrollTo(0,0), depending on your preference.

Edit: Updated with fixed code.

Comment: Thanks, but that is for a listView. The equivalent for a gridView would be .scrollTo(0,0) but still doesn't work! Maybe I should call it at a different location since I am calling it in onResume...I have also tried calling it in onPause but still doesn't work. (Even before or after the calls to the respective super methods)

Comment: Can you do other operations on the GridView in onResume?

Comment: Where should it be done then if you may help...??! The main aim is to scroll the gridView such that it displays the added item which will be at the first position, even if the activity to add the item was started when the scroll was not at the first position.

Comment: I'm not sure, that's why I was asking. Have you tried doing other operations to the GridView in onResume to see if it's something related to being in onResume? For example, try gridView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE) in onResume to see if it does anything. If it does, you know it's something more related to the adding and scrolling to the new item. If it doesn't make the GridView invisible, you know it's something related to calling it in onResume.

Comment: The methods onCreate and onResume are doing preparations for the activity. Although changing visual parameters of a view is allowed there, the modifications that involve animations or gradual changes might not work smoothly because while the process in in these methods the activity hasn't been fully initiated yet. It is a good practice to request gradual changes either out of these methods or, if in these methods then by post(...) or postDelayed(...) methods, which will post the actions to the event queue. Play with this, have a try...

Comment: That is true...I have played around with it...I have eventually decided to call activity in the form of ActivityForResult and then upon return, do what I want to do...see my answer above. Thanks everyone!